# How do I see what items the users have limited access to in our SharePoint Online site?

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, user, item-level-permissions

In our SharePoint Online site's permissions page, I see we have a few users with "Limited Access" permission levels.

My question is how do I see what items (Files, folders, etc) do these users have limited access to?:

[image]

Comment: They are having limited access at site level. They may have different level of permissions on lists/items/libraries/files/folders, etc.